# iptables port forwarding to different local addresses

Tags: iptables

I would like to forward local traffic to 127.0.0.2:30041 to 127.0.0.2:40041 and 127.0.0.3:30041 to 127.0.0.3:40041.

When I use
`sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 30041 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 40041`
all traffic is imply forwarded to 127.0.0.1:40041.

I tried

`sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -d 127.0.0.2 -p udp -m udp --dport 30041 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 40041`

as well as

`sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.2 -p udp -m udp --dport 30041 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 40041`

but traffic is still forwarded to 127.0.0.1 only.

Suspiciously, the resulting rules show that the `-d 127.0.0.2` option appears to be ignored, the `destination` is simply `localhost`:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -v -L OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   357 REDIRECT   udp  --  any    any     anywhere             localhost            udp dpt:30041 redir ports 40041
    6 10018 DOCKER     all  --  any    any     anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
```

How can I get iptables to forwards to a specific local address?